# drupal migrate source csv

Tags: migrations

I am trying to use 'migrate source csv' to migrate some content with taxonomy terms in drupal 8. If the field has only one term, I can use the following and it works out fine`process:
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: adi
  title: title
  field_description: description
  body: note
  field_subject_terms:
    plugin: entity_generate
    source: subject_terms
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:node'`

However, if it has more than one term, and I try with the following code, I get an error about th term is not an integer. I have also tried adding the iterator plugin to the code below, but still the same error.`process:
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: adi
  title: title
  field_description: description
  body: note
  field_subject_terms:
    plugin: explode
    source: subject_terms
    delimiter: ','
    process:
      plugin: entity_generate
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:node'
migration_dependencies: null`

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

'process' is not recursive - you can't simply embed processing within another plugin in the general case (only iterator has that ability). Rather, plugins (generally) need to be executed in sequence:

```
field_subject_terms:
  # First step in the processing pipeline.
  -
    plugin: explode
    source: subject_terms
    delimiter: ','
  # Results of the first step are passed through to the second step.
  -
    plugin: entity_generate
```